# dynamically add inputs by number in input[number] angularjs

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am trying to dynamically add and remove inputs by typing the number in

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="20">
```

I do not want you to make it for me just give me an idea how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your inputs in an `ng-repeat` with an array created by a change to your first input.

```
<input type="number"
       ng-model="size"
       ng-change="sizeArray = new Array(size)"
       min="1" 
       max="20">
<input ng-repeat="i in sizeArray track by $index"
       ng-model="inputValues[$index]">
```

You'll end up with an array of input values in your scope that will persist even when your input size changes.

Comment: Does it need some additional javascript code? It looks like an easiest way.

Comment: Assuming I remember the abilities of ‘ng-change’ correctly, that should work as-is. There are definitely ways to clean it up a bit by moving some of the logic to your controller though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get your started..

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("soDemo", []);
  app.controller("soDemoController", SoDemoController);

  SoDemoController.$inject = ['$scope', '$document'];

  function SoDemoController($scope, $document) {
    var vm = {
      count: 0,
      values: [],
      fillSequence: fillSequence
    };

    $scope.vm = vm;
    return;

    /////////// IMPLEMENATION ////////
    function fillSequence(limit) {
      var sequence = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        sequence.push(i);
      }
      
      return sequence;
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="sample" ng-app="soDemo" ng-controller="soDemoController">
  <label>Counter:</label><input ng-model="vm.count" type="number" min="1" max="20">
  <h3>Inputs:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in vm.fillSequence(vm.count)">
      <input ng-model="vm.values[i]" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Values:</h3>
  <pre>{{vm.values | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- First bind change event for your number input with some event handler pass event object to event handler.
- in event handler get value entered by using `event.target.value`.
- now create one instance variable of type number array.
- in event handler populate that array by using value you have extracted something like this as

  `this.inputs= Array.from(Array(parseInt(value)).keys());`
- now in html iterate over array to render inputs something like this

  `<input type='text' *ngFor="let item of items">`

Comment: This question applies to AngularJS not Angular in this case (*ngFor is an Angular directive)